# Simple loop/repeat on hover in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a function that animates when a div is hovered on:

```
$('.left_scroll_button').hover(function(){
        $(".scrolling_list").stop().animate({scrollLeft: '-=5px'}, 1);
 });
```

This just animates the thing once. I want to repeat the animation continuously.. Is there some easy way to loop this? I tried to do this:

```
$('.left_scroll_button').hover.everyTime(10,function(){
    $(".scrolling_list").stop().animate({scrollLeft: '-=5px'}, 1);
 });
```

But this didn't work. If anyone can hep, that would be great!

Comment: You realize `hover = mouseenter + mouseleave` and you have just implemented `mouseenter` function. `mouseleave` is optional though.

Comment: How about `scrollLeft: '-=50px'` instead of iterating 10 times? Is that the effect you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hey Vega, yeah i realize the first thing, and as for the second - this is just a UI thing.. want it to go semi-continuously on hover, or jump on click.

Comment: You mean you want to keep animating until he is hovering the element?

Comment: Maybe? I want, when the mouse hovers and remains on the thing, to repeat the animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using the Complete Function of the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method to make a recursive call? Could probably be cleaned up a bit but something like this:

```
$(function () {
  $('.left_scroll_button').hover(
    function(){
       var element = $(".scrolling_list");
          (function(){
              element
               .stop()
               .animate({left: '+=5px'}, 100, arguments.callee);
          }());
       }, 
      function(){
         $(".scrolling_list").stop();
      });
 });​
```

Here is an example I've thrown together [in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/743qY/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using setInterval to establish the animation loop?